# Is it always necessary to prove the 'iff' in both directions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have an exercise in my course, which asks to prove $A \cup B = B \iff A \subseteq B$.

My proof is: Let $A \nsubseteq B$, that is, $\exists a \in A : a \notin B$. Then from the definition follows $a \in A \cup B = B$, in contradiction to the initial assertion. $\square$

Usually I see that it's much more rigorous to prove $\implies$, then $\impliedby$, but I'm not sure, if that's only an option or a strict rule — and specifically if my proof does the job in both directions or there are some gaps that I don't recognize. My script suggests a really long 10+ lines proof using the 'both directions style', but I myself don't really see this necessity at least here.

This being said, is it always a must to prove the 'iff' in both directions?

Comment: You may prove an iff statement by proving each direction individually or in a single step by only using implications which are themselves also biconditional.  Your proof however is not formed using biconditional statements and so only succeeds in proving the forward implication.  The reverse implication has yet to be proven.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think your comment answers what was intended better than the existing answer, so it might be worth posting it (or similar) as an answer.

Comment: Thanks! So what does exactly fail to show the reverse direction here? I've been thinking of the "then", of course, but this surely can't be only because of the word usage, can it?

Comment: I'm not sure what what I see here succeeds in proving _either_ direction. As far as I can see it assumes $A\not\subseteq B$ and _somehow_ arrives at a contradiction. If the "somehow" checks out, that would prove $A\subseteq B$ _in general_, but it doesn't seem to connect it to the other side of the biimplication.

Comment: @HenningMakholm is succeeds in proving $A\cup B=B\implies A\subseteq B$ via contradition by showing that if $A\not\subseteq B$ while at the same time as tacitly assuming $A\cup B=B$ it follows that there is some $a\in A\setminus B$ which is simultaneously in and not in $B$.

Comment: One thing that may be a time saver is that when you are proving one direction, show that the step is reversible. Then you are really proving both directions.

Comment: @MarkS. I agree on the whole, but would not have used "biconditional." I have extended my answer to illustrate a further point not captured in the comments. I was answering the headline question.

Comment: You haven't given *any* reason why $A \subset B$ should mean $A\cup B = B$?  What if there there is a $c \in A\cup B$ so that $c \not \in B$.  Or what if there is an $a\in A\cup B$ so that $a \not \in B$.  You haven't given any reason so far that those don't occur.  You've simply proven it one way and there's *nothing* in your argument at all the indicates the other way doesn't need to be proven as well.  I'm not sure why you think what you did goes both ways.  It just *doesn't*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're trying (without making it completely clear) to prove $A\cup B=B \Leftrightarrow A\subseteq B$ by showing that $A\cup B=B$ together with $A\not\subseteq B$ leads to a contradiction.

If you think that is a complete proof, how about this one, by the same principle:

> **Claim:** For any integer $n>2$, $$ n\text{ is prime} \iff n\text{ is odd} $$
>
> **Proof:** Assume that $n$ is prime and that $n$ is *not* odd. Then $n$ is even, so $n=2k$ for some $k$. But then $2$ divides $n$, which is a contradiction with $n$ being prime, since $n>2$. $\Box$

This seems to follow exactly the same logic as your proof -- namely, considering $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ to be proved because I have shown that $\neg Q$ and $P$ together lead to a contradiction.

But there are odd numbers that are not prime -- such as $9$ -- so the claim is not actually true.

Comment: This is a nice example.

Answer (score 3):

"iff" means it is true both ways. If you only prove one way, you haven't shown "iff".

---

You are supposing the right hand side false, and show that if this is so the left-hand side must be false also, giving a contradiction. So if the left-hand side is true, the right-hand side can't be false, so must be true. You have shown the forward implication.

But now you have also to show the reverse implication. Note that with sets, to prove equality you also have to prove two things - so to show $A\cup B=B$ observe that if $a\in B$ then $a\in A\cup B$ by definition of union, whence $B\subseteq A\cup B$

Suppose $A\subseteq B$ and $a\in A$ then $a\in B$ by the definition of a subset. And if $a\in B$ then $a\in B$. Now if $a\in A\cup B$ then in either case $a\in A$ or $a\in B$ then $a\in B$. So $A\cup B\subseteq B$.

Since each side of the proposed equality is contained in the other, they are indeed equal.

I wrote this out in detail because of the hidden two-way implication concealed within $=$.

Answer (score 0):

Left to right.  A $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B = B.
Right to left.  A squeeze proof.
B $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B $\subseteq$ B $\cup$ B = B.

Yes, iff, if and only if, means prove both directions.